# google webmaster tools content keywords come from robots.txt

Tags: google-search-console

Strange thing happened today. When I visited google webmaster tools I found out that the content keywords are only three instead of (a lot that are actually on my website) and they are:

```
 1. agent   
 2. disallow    
 3. user
```

And when I click on which one of the words, I get "found on the most popular page /robots.txt". I haven't done anything to my website or webmaster tools for a couple of days now, so I have no idea what could cause that.

Anyone with the same problem and solution? What can i do in situation like that?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a temp bug in Analytics. Wait some days (or a week) and check again this.
Usually it is good to ignore what google webmasters tools says about keywords.

Share your robots.txt file (I assume there is nothing wrong there)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the answer. Here is my robots.txt 
User-Agent: *
Disallow:

Comment: The content in your file is alright. These are on two lines right?

Comment: Your robots.txt file is in your root, right?
example.com/robots.txt

Comment: Yes, they are two lines, its in the root.

Comment: Well.. you don`t have to worry about and you don`t have to see such a problems. I cannot think up anything else.. Check if the robots.txt is not in you sitemap.xml file. If its there, remove it. 
But I think this problem will disappear with time.